# how to make ajax request from javascript for core php function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i am working on a core php project in which i want to call php function from javascript using ajax call request.i tried this but its not work.

js file:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        url:"/rootfolder/subfolder/action.php/test",
        success:function(response)
        {   
            if(response == 'true')
            {
                window.location.assign("home.html");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("wrong credencials");
            }
        },
        failure:function(response)
        {
            alert("there is an error.");
        }
        });
```

php file:

```
<?php
   include("../connection.php");
   function test()
   {
     //some stuff
   }
?>
```

please suggest some solution or provide any refrence.thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a PHP *function* from JavaScript. You can only make an HTTP request. That HTTP request might be handled by a PHP program. There is no built-in PHP feature that will let you specify a particular function to call.

You can examine `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to determine what data is in the URL after the script name and use that to determine what the PHP program should do.

```
if ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] === "test") {
    test();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have declared the test function but haven't called it, I think the error is from the php side.

```
<?php
   include("../connection.php");
   test();//call the function
   function test()//this is just function decleration
   {
     //some stuff
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a URL variable called method

```
/subfolder/action.php?method=test
```

And then in your PHP use that variable to call the function

```
<?php 
    $function = $_GET['method'];
    $function();

    function test()
    {
        //some stuff
    }
    ......
?>
```

There could be other solutions too...